# C++ Exception not caught by base class

Tags: c++, exception

I'm compiling the following code with Visual C++ 2017 (C++17 features are enabled)

```
int main() {
  try {
    // loot is some library that is linked as a dll
    auto game = loot::CreateGameHandle(loot::GameType::fonv, "c:\\something\\invalid", "C:\\something\\invalid");
    // throw std::invalid_argument("this works as expected");
  }
  catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "caught as exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cout << "caught as invalid_argument " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cout << "caught by ..." << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The compiler reports, as expected:

```
warning C4286: 'const std::invalid_argument &': is caught by base class ('const stdext::exception &') on line 8
```

However, the application output is

```
caught as invalid_argument Given game path "c:\something\invalid" does not resolve to a valid directory.
```

And it's not just changing the catch order or something, if I remove the last 2 catch blocks, the application crashes because of the unhandled exception.

How is that even possible? I'm assuming this is somehow related to compiler settings that make *my* std::exception be a different type from the one std::invalid_argument inside the library inherits from - but why then is *my* std::invalid_argument the same type as theirs?
Is there a way to fix this? Because that library throws a lot of different exception types and I can't really catch each one individually.

Comment: That sounds really weird. Can you reproduce this with a [MCVE] please? I understand that it will be difficult.

Comment: You should always start with the most specific exception. Then is `loot` compiled with VS2017 as well? I saw issues when the exception thrown by a library was not captured by other code because a mismatch in the runtime.

Comment: The fact that it says `stdext::exception` is a big red flag. Something's wonky here.

Comment: Is the dll compiled with the same system runtime?

Comment: Yes, loot is built with VS2017 as well, not sure if it's the exact same version though. Should that even matter?
What does stdext::exception signify? Afaict all std exceptions are declared in that namespace in visual studio and than included into std with a using-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Bloody hell, sorry for this.
It turns out the build system I was using added _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 to the preprocessor definitions. That's what's causing this.